# AVX2: U8 absolute difference

Tags: sse, simd, neon, avx, avx2

I'm new to AVX (came from ARM NEON), and was unpleasantly surprised that AVX lacks many U8 arithmetics, absolute difference being among them missing.

Hence I had to resort to `max(a,b)-min(a,b)` with the inline function:

```
static inline __m256i _mm256_abd_epu8(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
    return _mm256_sub_epi8(_mm256_max_epu8(a, b), _mm256_min_epu8(a, b));
}
```

I'm curious if there are more efficient ways dealing with this problem.

And yes, I'm aware of `_mm256_sad_epu8`, but I need the differences themselves, NOT the sum.

I'd appreciate any input, and it's ok with `AVX2`, disregarding any backward compatibility.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any trick for doing this with only 2 or fewer instructions.  (And the SSE version of this question doesn't have anything better either: [Compute the absolute difference between unsigned integers using SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380785/compute-the-absolute-difference-between-unsigned-integers-using-sse)).  It does mention the saturating method I used in this answer.

---

*Slightly* better on pre-Skylake: subtract both ways with unsigned saturation, then OR the results.  (Either a-b or b-a saturates to zero for each element.)

`_mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(a,b), _mm256_subs_epu8(b,a))`

On Haswell, `pmin`/`pmax` and `psub` only run on port 1 or port 5, but `por` can run on any of the three vector execution ports (0, 1, 5).

Skylake adds a 3rd vector-integer adder so there's no difference on that uarch.  (See http://agner.org/optimize/ and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, including Intel's optimization manual.)

This is also slightly better on Ryzen, where `VPOR` can run on any of P0123, but `PADD`/`PMIN` can only run on P013 according to Agner Fog's testing.  (Ryzen splits 256b vector ops into 2 uops, but it has the throughput for that to be useful.  It can't fill its 6-uop wide pipe using only single-uop instructions.)

Uops that can run on more ports are less likely to be delayed waiting for their assigned port (resource conflict), so you're more likely to actually get 2 cycle total latency with this (from both inputs being ready to the output being ready).  They're also less likely to contribute to a throughput bottleneck if there's competition for a specific port (like port 5 which has the only shuffle unit on Intel Haswell and later).

Comment: Wow, I cannot even imagine a more comprehensive answer. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: cheers, I thought you'd appreciate the microarchitectural stuff, so I went into more detail than I otherwise might have.

Comment: Absolutely!!!! Now I realize that I have to dig deeper into pipelines, and the link you gave is godsend.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Some of my other answers have some good stuff.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction.  Also some of my highest-voted answers, especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466