# Absolute value without branching or shifts, only add/sub and booleans

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, absolute-value, branchless

We got this problem at school for students that want to test themselves. I have spent quite some time on this but can't figure it out.

> You have 16-bit number in AX register, this number is signed. Get its
>   absolute value, the number in AX has to be unchanged
>    (EDIT: There isn't liminted number of registers, and the AX register can be changed but at the end of the function it needs to be the original number), and the answer
>   should be in BX. You can only use these instructions:
>   MOV, ADD, XOR, SUB, NOT, AND, OR, NEG.

It is quite easy to do with SAR the way compilers do, but without it it's not clear how to get any behaviour conditional on the sign bit.

Comment: the absolute value of the smallest value -2^16 can't be represented in 16 bits?

Comment: @qwr: The solution to that problem is that the input is signed, the result is unsigned.  So `0x8000` (`32768`) is the correct absolute value result for an input of `0x8000` (`-32768`).  This is easy in asm, a pain in the ass in C where you might have to write something like `(x < 0) ? 0U - x : (unsigned)x;` to avoid causing signed overflow UB.  But that converts `x` to unsigned *before* the subtract, so it might only be right for 2's complement.  IDK, C is really hard to use sometimes.

Comment: Related: [x86 assembly abs() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2639173) for efficient code without these restrictions on what instructions you can use.  (And the bottom half of my answer here.)

Comment: Update: `(x<0) ? 0U - x : x` is fully portable in C as an unsigned absolute value of a signed int or narrower input.  It doesn't depend on 2's complement or anything: on one's complement or sign/magnitude machines, the implicit conversion to `unsigned` will change the bit-pattern as part of modulo-reduction into the 0..UINT_MAX range which C guarantees.  And unsigned binary math is fully defined, so this does only depend on values not bit-patterns, as well as being free of signed-overflow UB.

Answer (score 3):

Silly idea #1: Lookup table.  That can't work in 16-bit real mode.  Even a whole 64kiB segment for a table isn't enough; we need twice that to be able to look up a 2-byte result for any possible 16-bit value.

We could do this with 32-bit addressing easily, like `xor ebx, ebx` / `mov bx, ax` / `mov bx, [table + ebx*2]`, if you can justify 128kiB of table data. :P

Fully within the rules, you could construct the table on the stack in 32-bit or 64-bit mode with `sub esp, 1<<17` and store the data with `mov word [esp+0], 0` / `mov word [esp + 2], 1` / etc.  Fully unrolled, no looping, so about 256kiB of machine code.  But again, this doesn't work in real mode and is a total joke for efficiency.

---

**We can use x86 partial register shenanigans to isolate the sign bit as a 0 / 1 integer:**

```
    xor  dx, dx           ; DX = 0
    mov  dl, ah           ; DX = AX>>8   (zero extended)
    add  dx, dx           ; DX <<= 1  shifts the sign bit alone into DH

    mov  dl, dh
    mov  dh, 0            ; DX = (AX<0) = sign bit of AX zero extended to 16-bit

    neg  dx               ; DX = 0 or -1
```

Or the last 3 instructions can be optimized to 2

```
    neg  dh               ; 0 or -1 according to sign bit of AX
    mov  dl, dh           ; duplicate to the full DX = 0 or -1
```

Jackpot; we have our `sar ax,15` or `cwd` value that has all bits 0 or all bits 1, broadcasting the sign bit of AX, ready to use with a 2's complement identity ([How to prove that the C statement -x, ~x+1, and ~(x-1) yield the same results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278518/how-to-prove-that-the-c-statement-x-x1-and-x-1-yield-the-same-results)) like compilers use (https://godbolt.org/z/n3yoUp).

Typically you'd use `xor ax, dx` / `sub ax, dx` to modify the original value.

I had previously thought the challenge required you to avoid modifying any *other* registers, otherwise the restriction on leaving AX unmodified is trivial and not worth making part of the challenge.  But I don't think it's possible without extra scratch space in memory or another register.  The edit clarified that there's no need for that.

```
    mov  bx, ax
    xor  bx, dx           ; ~x      or x
    sub  bx, dx           ; ~x + 1  or x
```

XOR with `-1` flips all the bits like NOT.  XOR with `0` is a no-op.

SUB with `-1` increments by 1, SUB with `0` is a no-op.  (`0` is the identity element for addition and xor.)

So this conditionally applies the 2's complement `-x = ~x + 1` identity.

---

PS: It took me several minutes of head-scratching to think of this, ruling out any full-register approaches, and I'm *very* familiar with x86 and pretty familiar with bit-manipulation, e.g. writing codegolf.SE answers in x86 machine code and doing non-trivial stuff with SIMD.  **IMO this is a fun hard challenge.**

Also, you'd never want to write code like this in real life; `cwd` or `cdq` is much more efficient, or for source regs other than AX, copy and `sar`.  The partial-register stuff will even cause stalls on some out-of-order execution CPUs like Intel PPro through Nehalem.

---

For example, on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cHkXdo) for this source:

```
unsigned absval(int x) {
    return x<0 ? 0U - x : x;
}
```

Using an unsigned return value allows us to avoid signed-integer overflow undefined behaviour for the most-negative 2's complement integer.  (`-INT_MIN` is undefined behaviour).  I think the way I wrote it actually relies on the C implementation being 2's complement, though, because `0U - x` converts `x` to unsigned to match the other side *before* using it as an operand to binary `-`.  Or maybe that's what we want, for unsigned `0U-x` to produce `0x8000` from an input of `0x8000` (for 16-bit int).

GCC does this to set EAX = abs(EDI)  (x86-64 System V calling convention).

```
    mov     eax, edi
    cdq                      ; sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX
    xor     eax, edx
    sub     eax, edx
    ret
```

clang does this for x86-64, using a conditional move that reads flags from NEG:

```
    mov     eax, edi
    neg     eax                 ; 0 - x
    cmovl   eax, edi            ; copy the original if 0 was < x
    ret
```

it would have been more efficient on some CPUs to do:

```
    ; shorter critical path on CPUs where mov is not zero latency
    xor     eax, eax
    sub     eax, edi            ; 0 - x
    cmovl   eax, edi            ; copy the original if 0 was < x
    ret
```

Sandybridge eliminates xor-zeroing but not mov, and for CPUs that don't do `mov` elimination this shortens the critical path.  `mov eax,edi` is on the critical path but `xor`-zeroing isn't.  Or we could have done `mov eax, edi` / `neg edi` / `cmovnl eax, edi` to again allow MOV and NEG to run in parallel.

CMOV is a 2-uop instruction on Intel CPUs before Broadwell.  (CMOVA and CMOVBE are still 2 uops on current Intel because they read CF *and* ZF, which are renamed separately in different groups.  Others are 1 uop)

Comment: Our profesor gives this out every semester, and he said that over the 10 years he's been there only 7 people ware able to do it, and there is like 800 freshmen every semester.

I did it with SAR quite simple: 
`mov ax, [esp+8]
    
    mov bx, ax
    sar bx, 15
    
    mov cx, ax
    add cx, bx
    xor bx, cx`

Comment: the OP was edited to say I believe you can use beyond two registers

Comment: @qwr: Yeah I noticed that; that makes the 2nd part not a challenge.  I might edit later when I have time.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I'm sorry i wasnt sure, so i had to ask the professor, it wasnt specified if it was enabled or not. I'm not super fimiliar with bitwise operations, so your explanation was very helpful, thanks again.

Comment: @AdamĎuriník: Updated, glad to hear there wasn't supposed to be a way to do it without any scratch space that I was missing.  7 people over 10 years sounds about right for first-year students that are mostly beginners in asm coming up with this!  Thanks for passing that along.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Peter Cordes's answer, the code is quite simple, the problem was the SAR instruction, but Peter created it quite nicely.

The number is in already loaded to AX

```
; this is practicaly the SAR instruction, 
; the mask for the absolute value is 
; number >> (sizeof(short)) * CHAR_BIT -1)
; number >>        (2 * 8) - 1 = 15
; so normaly we would do SAR bx, 15 and done

mov bl, ah  ; BX = AX>>8
add bx, bx  ; BX <<= 1
neg bh      ; 0 or -1 
mov bl, bh  ; duplicate the full BX

mov cx, ax  ;
add cx, bx  ; the number + mask 
xor bx, cx  ; (number+mask) ^ mask
```

now the answer is in BX, and AX was not altered

Comment: "normally" you'd `cwd` to sign-extend AX into DX:AX, i.e. set DX = 0 or -1.  Anyway, in the first version of the question I though we weren't allowed to use any other registers, otherwise the restriction on not modifying AX is trivial.

Comment: I think you need an `xor bx, bx` at the beginning.