# x86 assembly abs() implementation? (revisited)

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, micro-optimization, absolute-value

[Extending this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639173/x86-assembly-abs-implementation), I was looking for a fast way to abs %ax.

I have two options, I will call them arithmetic and conditional, and avoid stack management for semplicity:

```
    absax:
        cwd
        xor %dx, %ax
        sub %dx, %ax
        ret
```

The arithmetic version extends the sign of %ax into %dx, so the way it works is:
`x = (~x) -(-1)` in case the sign bit is 1, essentially performing a `neg` operation.

```
    absax:
        mov %ax, %dx
        neg %ax
        cmovs %dx, %ax
        ret
```

This version is in my opinion simpler to understand and remember, and actually it is [what gcc prefers](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9Yffn8ab).
However I was not able to easily find human opinion about the conditional version. I was only able to find the arithmetic version, so I want to know once and for all what the best version is, and if my preferred one is inferior in any way.

NOTE:
After searching for a bit more I found some discussion on the conditional version as well, actually it was present in the original answer, I am deeply sorry.
However, I still feel that this question is an attempt to better address the differences between the two approaches.

Comment: Should it be specifically `ax` the 16-bit register, without affecting the other bits of the register?

Comment: @harold yes, I want to abs a word in this case. But a general solution for variable register sizes is much apreciated.

Comment: @ugo_capeto Note that it is likely a lot faster if you do a 32-bit abs instead.  The main reason the conditional version isn't used is that `cmov` is not available on old CPUs.  I would do `xor %dx, %dx; sub %ax, %dx; cmovns %dx, %ax` instead as some CPUs have errata that disable move elimination and others can fuse `cmov` with preceding instructions.

Comment: @fuz: Which CPUs have fusion of `cmovcc` or `setcc`?  I was only aware of AMD and Intel doing fusion with `jcc`.  But yes, I'd prefer `xor`-zero / `sub` to take `mov` off the critical path on old CPUs, and Ice Lake.  (Zen 3 and later fully eliminate xor-zeroing like Intel SnB-family does, and the same way Zen does for `mov`; older AMD and Gracemont need a back-end uop to write the zero.  https://chipsandcheese.com/2021/12/21/gracemont-revenge-of-the-atom-cores/ note the throughputs for "Zero Register using XOR" vs. "Independent Register to Register MOVs")

Comment: @ugo_capeto: harold was asking if you needed to leave the upper 48 bits of RAX unmodified like you're doing here, or if it would be ok to for example sign-extend AX into EAX or RAX as part of this.  Or leave garbage in them.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was pretty sure the more recent ones do it, but I can't seem to find any evidence right now.

Comment: @fuz: It's unlikely for `cmov` on Intel; Intel uops can only keep track of 3 operands (including one output), and `cmp a,b` / `cmov c,d` would have four inputs.  (And one output because I used `cmp` not `sub`.)  One register + FLAGS counts as one output since it's one PRF entry, but `sub` and `cmov` with separate outputs would be two outputs.  AMD could perhaps do this, they manage single-uop `vpblendvb` with 3 inputs + a separate output, but that's still only 3 input dependencies.  `cmp`+`cmov` has 4 input dependencies to wait for.  `cmp+setcc` is plausible.

Comment: @fuz: In Skylake at least, Intel's decoders route `setcc` to the complex decoder, and `setbe` is 2 uops even though it's not clear why that's necessary.  The destination register (to merge into the bottom) is only a 3rd input, not a 4th like `cmova` or `cmovbe`  (2 registers + both parts of FLAGS = CF + SPAZO).  [Can the simple decoders in recent Intel microarchitectures handle all 1-µop instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61980149).  Later Intel does fusion after decode, though, so even with that low-effort decode it could still handle it differently.  And IDK about AMD.

Comment: @PeterCordes It wouldn't surprise me if it's so the latency is 1 cycle for when the register is split and you carry on with only the low half.  Putting the merge in with the ALU operation would mean you always had to wait for the upper half

Comment: @fuz: For `setcc`?  On Skylake and Haswell, it does have a false dependency. Same for byte loads (micro-fused load+ALU-merge), that's why we use `movzx` to load bytes.  Intel hasn't renamed low-8 partial registers since Ivy Bridge, and I don't expect them to start again.  [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hm... I don't really know much about this corner of the instruction set...